# Make layer with TileStache from MySQL database

Tags: mysql, tilestache

I am unsuccessful in attempt to make layer with TileStache whitch gets data from MySQL. I found simple MySQL table structure (http://howto-use-mysql-spatial-ext.blogspot.com/):

```
create table Points ( 
name VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY, 
location Point NOT NULL, 
description VARCHAR(200), 
SPATIAL INDEX(location) 
);
```

and then

```
INSERT INTO Points (name, location) VALUES ( 'point1' , GeomFromText( ' POINT(31.5 42.2) ' ) )
```

For TileStache in tilestache.cfg I got:

```
"data":
    {
        "provider": {"name": "vector", "driver": "MySQL",
                     "parameters": {"dbname": "gis", "port": "3306", 
                     "user": "root", "password": "root",
                     "table" : "points"}}
    },
```

When I go to http://localhost:8080/data/ I get in console:

> - GET http://localhost:8080/data/10/167/395.png 500 (Internal Server
>     Error);
> - GET http://localhost:8080/data/null 400 (Bad Request).

Same internal error when going to http://localhost:8080/data/0/0/0.geojson

NOTE: http://localhost:8080/osm/ works fine.

I think problem is global, because I tried making layer from .json file, but same result

Answer (score 0):

Why changing ports. make sure when you start tilestache-server it listens to the correct port and make sure that by going to localhost:port_of_tilestatche it shows.
 belows tilestache

Comment: I got some java program running at that port. I stopped it, but still the same errors when listening on port 8080.

Answer (score 0):

Try running tilestache on a different port. Port 8080 has many things running on it. What OS are you using
    tilestache-server.py -c your config file  -p 9000

Then you can run localhost:9000 and you should get the

Comment: Port 8080 is ok. The example code "osm" works (http://localhost:8080/osm/). But anyway tried 9000 still the same.